# After Update F5 and F6 keys stopped working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

So I'm using Ubuntu Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) and I have external keyboard Keychron K3A1. It's all been working fine for a few years until some time ago, maybe a few weeks back, when after one of the overnight ubuntu updates made the F5 and F6 keys to stop working.

Here's the output of `showkey`:

```
petar@xps~$ sudo showkey
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
// HERE I PRESS F5 and F6 multiple times but nothing is registered
keycode  29 press
^Ccaught signal 2, cleaning up...
petar@xps~$
```

and same thing is with `xev`. Oddly enough - it is not a keyboard broken key because `Fn` + `F5` and `Fn` + `F6` is working fine (dimming the keyboard light and brightening the keyboard light).

And one more strange thing happened too. I have a key on my Keychron keyboard that is supposed to take a screenshot. It was working fine, but at the same time when the other problem started happening, this key stopped working and in stead of getting a screenshot it now opens a new terminal. I think somehow now it is mapped to `Ctrl` + `Shift`:

```
petar@xps~$ sudo showkey
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
keycode  42 press     // <----!!!!! This is where I press the screenshot key.
keycode 125 press
keycode   5 press
keycode  42 release
keycode 125 release
keycode   5 release
keycode 272 press
keycode 272 release
keycode  29 press
^Ccaught signal 2, cleaning up...
petar@xps~$
```